# Access custom table

Tags: model, resource-model

I realize there are tons of  tutorials online, I've looked at them, followed them and they work but now I'm trying to create my own model and I seem to be missing something. My problem: When I try to run my indexAction it just displays NULL, I have put data into my table and yes my table does exist. The table name is fit with fit_id being the primary key

Here is my config file

```
<models>
        <krauskopf_ymm>
            <class>Krauskopf_Ymm_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>ymm_resource</resourceModel>
        </krauskopf_ymm>

        <ymm_resource>
            <class>Krauskopf_Ymm_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <krauskopf_ymm>
                    <table>fit</table>
                </krauskopf_ymm>
        </entities>
        </ymm_resource>

</models>
```

Here is my Model, Krauskopf/Ymm/Model/Ymm.php

```
<?php
class Krauskopf_Ymm_Model_Ymm extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract{

  public function _construct(){

    $this->_init('krauskopf_ymm/ymm');
  }

 }
```

Here is my Resource Krauskopf/Ymm/Model/Resource/Ymm.php

```
<?php
class Krauskopf_Ymm_Model_Resource_Ymm extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract{

 protected function _construct(){

    $this->_init('krauskopf_ymm/ymm', 'fit_id');
 }

}
```

Here is my collection Krauskopf/Ymm/Model/Resource/Ymm/Collection.php

```
<?php
class Krauskopf_Ymm_Model_Resource_Ymm_Collection extends     Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract{

  protected function _construct(){
    $this->_init('krauskopf_ymm/ymm');
  }

}
```

When I try to run my indexAction it just displays NULL, I have put data into my table and yes my table does exist. The table name is fit with fit_id being the primary key

IndexController.php

```
    public function indexAction(){
    $model = Mage::getModel('krauskopf_ymm/ymm');
    $data = $model->getData(1);
    var_dump($data);

}
```

Comment: I had to change the file structure to put my "resource" into Model/Mysql4 and extend my Ymm.php from Mysql4_Abstract. Then I had to move my Ymm/Collection.php file into Model/Mysql4/Ymm/Collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `$data = $model->getData(1);` with

```
$model->load(1);
$data = $model->getData()
```

Comment: I now get this error from my error log. 

codkra-osx:~ codkra$ /Users/codkra/Documents/Magento/var/report/1114252767197 ; exit;
/Users/codkra/Documents/Magento/var/report/1114252767197: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
/Users/codkra/Documents/Magento/var/report/1114252767197: line 14: `#13 {main}";s:3:"url";s:14:"/Krauskopf_Ymm";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}'